# How can I maintain long-term local files alongside Git-controlled files?

Tags: git, ignore

Let's say I have a code base versioned with Git. Alongside the code itself, I have some project files eg. a Qt Creator `.pro.user` file, or a Sublime Text `.sublime-project` file. Or maybe it's a local config file with my own personal settings for the project. Or a shell script that I find useful but isn't relevant to other developers.

If I just keep these files alongside the code, they will be deleted when I clean the tree eg. with `git clean -fdx`. This will be the case even if I add them to the `.gitignore` file, because that usually contains entries for build by-products that you *do* want to delete.

Is there any way to tell Git "ignore these files for version control purposes, but also don't obliterate them when cleaning?" Or is there a way to get the `clean` command to distinguish between files that are ignored because they're intermediate build cruft, and files that are ignored because you don't want them shared with other developers? Something that will survive a `clean` or a `reset --hard`?

Answer (score 0):

There is to my knowledge no way of accomplishing this in a sane way while keeping `git clean -fx` from removing them. If these files are needed but are not part of the project, I would see if it is possible to have whatever creates them store them elsewhere. Otherwise, I would add them to either `.gitignore` or your global excludes file depending on whether they are project-specific or system-specific, and avoid `git clean`ing them away.

Furthermore, while it may be safe to assume that these particular files do not affect the behaviour of your program, in the general case you probably want to make sure that this is in fact so, and therefore it would be a good idea to *not* do what you propose, even if it were possible.

I suppose you could create a separate branch, orphaned if you prefer (`(git checkout --orphan`), and commit the files there. Then you could `git checkout thatbranch -- files` to grab the files. It's not optimal, but at least you'll know that your files are safe.

Comment: *in the general case you probably want to make sure that this is in fact so* — sure, but the same could be said for environment variables, or even (as you suggest) those same project/config files but in a different location. To some extent that's why it's always a good idea to have a stateless CI setup. I just want to avoid having a hundred project files etc. in my projects' parent directory, or losing data when IDEs enforce this metadata location (eg. Qt Creator).

Comment: Indeed. I amended my answer with a workaround; I'm not sure if it's worth the hassle or not. But at least it'll keep the files safe from `git clean`, since they are easily restorable.